# Products after sorting

Tags: entropy

Given two sets $\{a_1, \dots, a_N\}$ and $\{ b_1, \dots, b_N \}$ of positive numbers $0 < a_i, b_i < 1$, $i=1, \dots, N$, is it true that $\sum_i \min(a_i, b_i) \cdot \sum_i \max(a_i, b_i) \le \sum_i a_i \cdot \sum_i b_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cumbersome way to prove this is by induction, and it seems it holds not only for probabilities, but also for all integers. It's apparent that this holds for $N=1$. Now, assume it holds for $N=n-1$, and let's query for $N=n$. For taking advantage of the result for $N=n-1$, we arrange the terms as below: 
$$\begin{align}&\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\min(a_i,b_i)+\min(a_n,b_n)\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\max(a_i,b_i)+\max(a_n,b_n)\right) \\ &\overbrace{\leq}^?\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i+a_n\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}b_i+b_n\right)\end{align}$$
We expand the terms and since the inequality holds for $n-1$, the part that needs proving is (assuming $a_n\leq b_n$ without loss of generality):
$$a_n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\max(a_i,b_i)+b_n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\min(a_i,b_i)\overbrace{\leq}^? a_n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}b_i+b_n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i$$
$$a_n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(\max(a_i,b_i)-b_i)\overbrace{\leq}^? b_n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(a_i-\min(a_i,b_i))$$
Now, consider the LHS and RHS sums. When $a_i\leq b_i$, the summands are $0$. Then, we're only left with positive terms in indices, $I$, where $a_i>b_i$, and the sum reduces to:
$$a_n\sum_{I}(a_i-b_i)\overbrace{\leq}^? b_n\sum_I (a_i-b_i)\rightarrow a_n\overbrace{\leq}^? b_n$$
which is our initial assumption. Logically, one can reach a true conclusion from a wrong statement, however these operations can be replicated backwards, which makes it a $\iff$ statement. So, the inequality is true. Note that, I just assumed $a_n\leq b_n$ for notational simplicity. The expression in the end would look like $\min(a_n,b_n)\leq \max(a_n,b_n)$ if I didn't assume $a_n<b_n$, and the lines would look more populated.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it might be possible to find an explicit expression for the difference $\sum_i a_i \cdot \sum_i b_i - \sum_i \min(a_i, b_i) \cdot \sum_i \max(a_i, b_i)$?

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible to further simplify that expression

Comment: Actually, I think it might be :-) Let's call $m_i = \frac{a_i + b_i}{2}$ and $d_i = \frac{|a_i - b_i|}{2}$ then we have $\min(a_i, b_i) = m_i - d_i$ and $\max(a_i, b_i) = m_i + d_i$. We then have $\sum_i min(a_i, b_i) = \sum_i m_i - \sum_i d_i$ and $\max(a_i, b_i) = \sum_i m_i + \sum_i d_i$ thus $\sum_i \min(a_i, b_i) \cdot \sum_i \max(a_i, b_i) = \left( \sum_i m_i \right)^2 - \left( \sum_i d_i \right)^2$. What do you think?

Comment: Actually, I find the transformation clever :). But, when you substitute $a_i,b_i$ back, the entire expression isn't clearer than before. So, it's merely changing variables; does not seem like a simplification. For example, let the entire expression be $e=\sum_i a_i ...$. Is it a simplification?